# Get image with includegraphics from remote computer

Tags: floats

Is there a way to grab a figure from another computer (and enter the password in the console or via command line)?  For example, is there a way to do this?

```
 \begin{figure}

 \includegraphics{user@xxx.xyz:/home/user/pic.pdf}

 \end{figure}
```

Thank you

Comment: It would (nost likely) be possible to use the shell escape feature to launch a copy command but it's simpler just to copy them to the local machine first.

Comment: In Linux and the like, you can mount temporarily or permanently (when available) `ssh` locations with `sshfs`; passwordless logins with public keys can be set up.

Answer (score 1):

ConTeXt can grab files via HTTP. When you mean SSH with “remote computer”
then, I'm afraid it's not supported. Here's an example how to use a graphic
via HTTP. Since there's no graphic extension provided I added the `method`
option.

```
\starttext
  \externalfigure [http://placekitten.com/g/800/600][method=jpg]
\stoptext
```

The easiest solution would probably be to set up an HTTP server to
provide access to the files.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it can be done (as DavidCarlisle says), but the problem is that the resulting file can't be shipped around (much). Besides, placing the password in the LaTeX source is a security risk.

Presumably you want to grab the image because it isn't fixed. What I do anyway is to use `make` (under Linux) to build my more complex documents (compile images from their [asymptote](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/), [dia](http://www.gnome.org/projects/dia/) or other format, translate some SVGs to PDF, ...) and then run `pdflatex` and `bibtex` as needed. Perhaps add other information, like exact version from [git](http://git-scm.com) or do other stuff that is hard ro do in LaTeX. I'd just add the "grab the image" in there.